# Code coverage from Jest to stdout to GitLab

Tags: jestjs, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I am running jest test with code coverage in GitLab CI and GitLab captures the percentage from stdout of a runner in gitlab.

`jest --coverage` produces the coverage in stdout and gitlab captures it using `/All files[^|]*\|[^|]*\s+([\d\.]+)/` regexp but when I run 
`jest --coverage --json --outputFile=xyz.json` sadly jest doesn't print the code coverage to stdout.

What can I do to get code coverage in stdout from jest when `--json` arguments is given to jest?

`jest version : v22.4.3` same for jest-cli

Answer (score 43):

The following configuration will let GitLab interpret the coverage report generated by [Jest](https://jestjs.io):

```
stages:
  - test

Unit tests:
  image: node:12.17.0
  stage: test
  script:
    - jest --coverage
  coverage: /All\sfiles.*?\s+(\d+.\d+)/
```

There's an [open issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/45556#note_98659608) on GitLab which contains the correct regex for coverage reports generated using Jest (which is used by [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev)).

Comment: I'm still having this problem. I opened a ticket on gitlab. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/231573

Answer (score 12):

I'm using the following regex to parse the `text-summary` coverage reports from Jest for Gitlab: `/^(?:Statements|Branches|Functions|Lines)\s*:\s*([^%]+)/`

Note that Gitlab will only consider the **last match** though. So above could be written as `/^Lines\s*:\s*([^%]+)/`. I included the full example so that you can choose the one that makes the most sense for your project.

Since Gitlab 15 you need to provide this regex in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for the `coverage` key and no longer in the Gitlab Project Settings.

The "text-summary" report looks like this in StdOut:

```
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 80.49% ( 2611/3244 )
Branches     : 65.37% ( 923/1412 )
Functions    : 76.48% ( 582/761 )
Lines        : 80.44% ( 2583/3211 )
================================================================================
```

Make sure you have included `text-summary` as a coverage reporter in your `jest.config.js`:

```
coverageReporters: ['text-summary', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Jest, but if you are creating a JSON the simplest way would be to simply `cat` the JSON then change the regex accordingly

Comment: json stores the data of snapshots and statics about passed and failed test it don't have any data related coverage

Comment: i even tried looking in coverage folder coverage-final.json has info only about which lines were covered not the how many percentage of lines were covered?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2927 this guy had same issue but they closed it