# What regex to use to capture jest text code coverage report from gitlab ci

Tags: jestjs, gitlab-ci

I have Jest that generates code coverage report in text format and I want gitlab ci to capture the result :

I was using the following regex :

```
/All\sfiles.*?\s+(\d+.\d+)/
```

that I found here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/45556#note_98659608 & here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200539/14813425

but then I encountered an issue when the statement coverage is an integer with no decimal part because it took the branch coverage (a drop in the code coverage displayed by gitlab) :

```
All files                                                                   |      46 |    12.42 |   41.63 |   46.58 |
```

What regex can I use that handle the case where jest returns an integer for statement coverage ?

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this one that handles both case integer & decimal for the statement coverage :

```
/All\sfiles.*?\s+([\d\.]+)/
```